# Tricky integral, Euler, $ \int \frac{x^{n+2}\ dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}} $

Tags: complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int \frac{x^{n+2}\ dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}} = \frac{n+1}{n+2} \int \frac{x^n \ dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+2} \sqrt{1-x^2} $$

It is said that it can be solved by integration by parts. I've spend last few hours checking *almost* every possibility, as $ u = x^{n+1}, x^{n+2} ...\ dv = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}x}  $ etc. I've surely wasted half of the forest (poor Euler) writing such monster equations with five or more integrations by parts inside. I would be thankful for any help.

I'm a little bit afraid that solution is really easy but probably weariness wouldn't help me.

(source: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~reznick/sandifer.pdf page 10)

Comment: Maybe, and just maybe, you could write $$\int \dfrac{x^{n+2}dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\dfrac{1}{n+3}\int \dfrac{d(x^{n+3})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$And then do something? Also, maybe you could use $\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=d(\arcsin(x))$ to get $$\int \dfrac{x^{n+2}dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int x^{n+2}d\arcsin(x)=\arcsin(x)x^{n+1}-\int (n+2)\arcsin(x)x^{n+1}dx$$This seems more closer.

Comment: You can easily integrate $dx / \sqrt{(1-x^2)} x$?  I'd think $\int x\,dx / \sqrt{(1-x^2)}$ would be easier.

Comment: Another approach: the $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ piece suggests a substitution $x = \cos \theta$.  Could be useful if you're more comfortable manipulating trig functions than square roots.

Comment: Thanks for yours responses!
@SanathDevalapurkar I've tried this way and (for my tired mind) it seems as dead end. It's self-looping (the same integral with the same sign on the both sides) or hardcore way through arcsin integrals, which not seems as correct way.  

aschleper Sure, it would be easier, but I cannot see where exactly it would be helpful (in the topic-integral).  
  
Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by parts, without the trig. Let $I_n=\int \frac{x^n \ dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},$ and consider the integral
$$J_n=\int \frac{x^n(1-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$
On the one hand it is $I_n-I_{n+2}$ by expanding the numerator. On the other hand, simplifying the integrand of $J_n$ to $x^n \sqrt{1-x^2},$ we can integrate $J_n$ by parts with $u=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $dv=x^n\ dx.$ This gives 
$$J_n = \sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}I_{n+2}.$$ If we now equate the two versions of $J_n$ and solve for $I_{n+2}$ we arrive at the reduction formula at the top of the question.

Comment: Whoa, huge. Thank you, very clearly and impressing!

Comment: You're welcome. I had done a similar reduction formula in which the radical in the denominator didn't have $x^2$ but was instead $\sqrt{1-x}$ or maybe $\sqrt{1+x}.$ I think the same trick would work for any denominator $\sqrt{1 \pm x^k}.$

Answer (score 1):

By letting $x=\sin t$, these become the famous [Wallis integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals), whose recurrence relation is proven in the linked article.

Comment: +1! How do you think Euler evaluated it - with or without Wallis integrals?